# How to set different alignment rules for different subequations?

Tags: equations, align, subequations

I need to group three lengthy equations with `{subequations}`, here is my code:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}\label{4a}
    x ={}& 11111111111111111111111111111
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}\label{4b}
    y ={}& 2222222222222222222222222222222
\end{split}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}\label{4d}
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx={}& aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
     &-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

This is the output:
[image]
There are two issues:

1, Equations 1a, 1b, 1c are not aligned, I need to align them to the left(like the image below).

2, There is a line break between 1b and 1c, I need to remove it.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

EDIT: This is what I mean by "align them to the left":
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why are you nesting `split`? And what kind of alignment are you thinking to? At the `=` signs?

Comment: @egreg, Oh, I need to align different equations to the left, and break those lengthy equations into several lines. Those lines from the same equation should be aligned like (1c). Nesting `split` seems unnecessary in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue with setting lengths `\abovedisplayskip` (space above `\begin{align}`), `\belowdisplayskip` (space below `end{align}`) and `\jot` (space between equations in `align`). Your aim is to have `\belowdisplayskip+\abovedisplayskip=\jot`, so the space between equations 1(b) and 1(c) is equal to space between 1(a) and 1(b). It can be done in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
some text some text
\newlength{\someskip}
\setlength{\someskip}{\belowdisplayskip}%<- to save current \belowdisplayskip
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}\label{4a}
    x ={}& 11111111111111111111111111111
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}\label{4b}
    y ={}& 2222222222222222222222222222222
\end{split}
\end{align}%*
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{\jot}% *
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\someskip}%* <- restore \belowdisplayskip to normal value
\begin{align}
\begin{split}\label{4d}
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx={}& aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
     &-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
some text some text

\end{document}
```

% at the end of lines with * is crucial. Otherwise will give here extra line and you want to have no characters between \end{align} and \begin{align}.

I added some text to visualise skips before and after `align`.

Answer (score 1):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{gather}
    x = 11111111111111111111111111111    \label{4a}   \\
    y = 2222222222222222222222222222222  \label{4b}   \\
\begin{multlined}[t][0.75\linewidth]\label{4d}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
     -bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
\end{multlined}
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by “align them to the left”. Here's how you can align at the `=` signs.

Note that `={}&` is very rarely needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\label{4a}
    x &= 11111111111111111111111111111
\\
\label{4b}
    y &= 2222222222222222222222222222222
\\
\begin{split}\label{4d}
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx &= aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
     &\qquad-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\label{4a}
  & x = 11111111111111111111111111111
\\
\label{4b}
 & y = 2222222222222222222222222222222
\\
 & \begin{aligned}[b]
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx= aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
  {}-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
\end{aligned}\label{4d}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]